# How to use string matching column excluding numeric

Tags: sql-server

I want to match a string where last concatenation of numeric must be ignore.

i.e. Emp_Doc table

```
doc_ID      EmpID              Doc_name
---------------------------------------------
1            1                   LeaveOrder1
1            1                   LeaveOrder2                       
3            1                   Appointment_Order
------------------------------------------------


i.e. DocMaster table

doc_ID               Doc_name
---------------------------------------------
1                    LeaveOrder   
2                    Leaving_Certificate
3                    Appointment_Order
------------------------------------------------
```

i want to fetch LeaveOrder1 and LeaveOrder2 with respect to match with document master. But how can i exclude last numeric in fetching

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your VARCHAR column contains numbers elsewhere, e.g.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20)
SET @str = 'Leave25Order1'
```

You can use this:

```
SELECT LEFT(@str, LEN(@str) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',  REVERSE(@str) ))
```

to get this:

```
Leave25Order
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will work if your string has numeric data in middle.

```
SET @str = 'LeaveOrder1'

SELECT CASE
         WHEN Patindex('%[0-9]%', RIGHT(@str, Len(@str) - 1)) > 0 THEN LEFT(@str, Len(@str) - 1)
         ELSE @str
       END
```

Comment: what if the trailing number has more than one digit?